# Close websocket without closing express app

Tags: node.js, express

I have an express backend which includes:

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
var expressWs = require('express-ws')(app);
```

and:

```
app.get(/test/, function(req, res){
    res.send('{"hello" : "world" }');
});

app.ws('/', function(ws, req) {
    ws.on('message', function(msg){
        var data = JSON.parse(msg);
        if(data.action == "login"){
              console.log("logged in!")
        }
    });
});
```

I want to be able to close the websocket without closing the app. How do I do this?

Answer (score 2):

ws.close() is what you are looking for

Answer (score 0):

***Here it is*** :

```
app.get(/test/, function(req, res) {
    res.send('{"hello" : "world" }');
});

app.ws('/', function(ws, req) {
  ws.on('message', function(msg) {
    var data = JSON.parse(msg);
    if(data.action == "login"){
      console.log("logged in!")
    }
  });

  ws.on('close', function(msg) {
    console.log('connection closed...');
  });
});
```